Correspondence between basepoint free linear systems and Holomorphic maps to $\mathbb{P}^n$
I am currently reading's Miranda's book on Riemann Surfaces. I have a question about codimension 1 subspaces of $L(D)$.
I am stuck on the proof of Propoisiton 4.15 in chapter 5. Questions regarding this proof have been asked at other places on MSE, but none of them seem to clarify this step: (here, and here)

Proposition 4.15: Let $Q \subset |D|$ be a base-point-free linear system of (projective) dimension n on a compact Riemann surface X. Then there is a holomorphic
map $\varphi : X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ such that $Q = |\varphi|$· Moreover $\varphi$ is unique up to the choice of
coordinates in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

In the proof, we treat $Q$ as the projectification of some linear $n+1$ dimensional subspace $V \subset L(D)$. We then choose a basis $f_0, \dots, f_n$ of $V$ and define the map $\varphi: X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ as  $p \mapsto [f_0(p): \dots : f_n(p)]$. Then it's said that $|\varphi| = Q$.
The last inequality is not proved, and that's where I am stuck. I tried the following:
Define $D' = -\text{min}_i\{\text{div}(f_i)\}$, then it's clear that $V \subset L(D') \subset L(D)$. Since $Q$ is basepoint free, from a previous lemma (4.8 and 4.9) we know that $V \not\subset L(D-p)$ for all $p \in X$.
I now want to show that all codimension 1 subspaces of $L(D)$ are of the form $L(D-p)$ for some point $p \in X$. Because if this is true, it will follow that $L(D') = V$ and consequently $|\varphi| = Q$.
If the statement about codimension 1 subspaces is untrue, how should I proceed?
Thanks.

The answer follows from $V \subset L(D') \subset L(D)$. It is enough to show that $L(D') = L(D)$ rather than the condition I asked in the question. For if $L(D) = L(D')$ then $|\varphi|  = \{\text{div}(g) + D' | g \in V\} = \{\text{div}(g) + D | g \in V\} = Q$. (The first and last equalities follow from definitions).
If $L(D') \subsetneq L(D)$ then there exists a meromorphic function $f \in L(D) \backslash L(D')$. This implies, at some point $p \in X$ $D'(p) < D(p) \Longrightarrow D'(p) \leq D(p) -1 \Longrightarrow D' \leq D - 1\cdot p$. Therefore, $L(D') \subset L(D-p)$.
This implies, $V \subset L(D-p)$. This contradicts the base point free hypothesis. Since $p$ is a basepoint of $Q$ iff $V\subset L(D-p)$.
And from this contradiction, it follows that $L(D) = L(D')$.
